# Where is samba login information stored on a client?

Tags: networking, login, samba

Before I tightened up my samba permissions I allowed anonymous logins.  On one of the PCs on my LAN I apparently once logged into a share anonymously and ticked the "remember forever" box on the login dialog.

Currently I don't allow anonymous logins, but every time I shut down this PC, I see a samba session "closed for user nobody" in the auth.log. (It doesn't open the session, so that part is OK).

Where are these "remember forever" samba logins saved? I'd like to remove it so I don't get these junk messages in my auth.log

(I checked `seahorse` but I didn't see anything relevant for user `nobody`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out it's in the keyring for `nobody`.  Here's how to fix it.

- log in as `nobody`

  `sudo su -s /bin/bash nobody`
- show keyring entries for `nobody`

  `keyctl show @us`

  (first entry is the keyring number, following lines are keys)
- confirm there is data in keyring

  `keyctl read [keyring number]`
- clear keyring

  `keyctl clear [keyring number]`
- confirm it worked

  `keyctl show @us`

  (should print only one line, no following keys)